# Display values of custom fields created on media entity in a template file

Tags: entities

I'm trying to display the values from the custom fields that have created on my `Media Entity` to my `page--media.html.twig` file. The fields that I'm trying to output are `Location` and `Photographer`

I tried using this code below, to make it work.

`{{ node.field_photographer.entity.value  }}`

Also tried an alternative

`{{ content.field_photographer.entity.value  }}`

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to access it from a page-level twig template, you'll need to add a preprocess hook to make those variables available to the template.  You can use the Devel module and Devel Kint submodule to output what variables are currently available at the page-level template and debug/confirm your preprocess hook works.

Comment: as @AnsonWHan said, probably you are in the wrong template to access the variables. You can check the [available Variables](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates) in all Twig-Files easy. Do you need help for the preprocess hook to get the variables in the page-template?

Comment: @btemperli I wasn't aware that I need to use a `preprocess_hook` in order to achieve this. I'm still new to drupal 8

Answer (score 3):

Your question is more about how to handle Drupal templates and passed variables. I suggest you to use [Devel and Devel Kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) modules to be able to debug variables just in your template like this:

`{{ kint() }}` - print all available variables

`{{ kint(your_var_name) }}` - print particular variable

And don't forget to enable [twig debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) - it will show you templates structure.

Once you have everything visible it becomes much easier to understand.